# How do i use navigation properties correctly EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Below is a POCO class i set up with Entity Framework Code first.  How can i Query my database so that I can return all brands of a specific category?

Example: You have a list of categories and you click on one.  It shows all brands of products available under that category.

I don't know if my classes are set up correctly to do this.

```
  public class Product
    {
        [Key,ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }


        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }


        public int? BrandID { get; set; }

        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }


    }


   public class Brand
    {

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int BrandID { get; set; }


        public string BrandName { get; set; }

    }


    public class Category
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create relation between `Brand` and `Category` if you gonna need such kind of information as all brands for category. Saying so I think you need either a `1:N` or `M:N` relationship b/w those two tables/entities?

Comment: I thought about that but, I wouldn't think brand would have a relation to category but more so to product. Product would have a relation to both Category and Brand. I guess am looking to see what the right way of doing it is.

Comment: I would prefer a foreign key relation even if you gonna need only this query. Otherwise you have to use `JOIN` and/or `UNION` with `LINQ` which I would try to escape. The foreign key scenario is easier and I think better way to deal with this.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean in a snippet?

Comment: I'll try. But could you specify the type of relation that you need? 1:N or M:N ?

Comment: 1:N would be right because a brand could be apart of many categories. But each category should only show each brand once. Does that make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25093/discussion-between-jackncoke-and-leron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
context.Products.
    Where(p => p.Category.CategoryID == categoryToFind).Select(p => p.Brand);
```

or

```
var brands = context.Products.
    Where(p => p.Category.CategoryID == categoryToFind).
    Select(p => p.Brand.BrandName).Distinct().ToList();
```

if you just need brand names.

Comment: What type of method would you wrap that in if you only wanted to return `Brandnames` back to the page? IQueryable or List?

Comment: @jackncoke Probably a method returning a `Distinct()` list of names. If there's not too many data maybe even pull everything client side and filter locally.